# Induction proving

Tags: induction

I have this problem I need to prove:

> Prove that for every $n\ge3$ this statement is true: $2^n\ge2n+1$

I proved this by induction and it was easy for me.
my question is about the second section of the question.

> Two sequences is given: $8, 16, 32, \dots, 2^n$ and $7, 9, 11, \dots, 2n+1$
>
>
> Prove that the sum of the geometric progression is bigger than the sum of the arithmetic progression. 
> Use Section A to prove it.

How do I prove it without using induction again? by logic I know this statement is true, but how do I write it in a formal way?
Thanks!

Comment: What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? It might help to review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Comment: From the first part: $2^3 \ge 7$, $2^4\ge 9$, $2^5 \ge 11$, ...

Comment: I tried to use strong induction, trying to put numbers that are bigger and equal to 3 and to see if that statement is true. But my lecturer told me no induction is necessary.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thank you, I fixed the text, I'm new to the site and I messed up the question.

Comment: You can show that the sum of the exponential series is $2^{n+1}-8$ and the sum of the arithmetic series is $(n+1)^2-9.$

Comment: @BeardGuy367 I don't think you can avoid induction driving your argument at some level, but I think your lecturer is saying you can hand-wave it a bit. Such as, "Because $2i + 1 \le 2^i$ for $i \ge 3$, we have $\sum_{i=3}^n (2i + 1) \le \sum_{i=3}^n 2^i$", or something similar.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes I think I'll go with that, I will write a verbal solution to this problem. I wanted to see if my logic is correct. Than you!

Answer (score 1):

Claim:
$$
\sum_{n=3}^k 2^n \geq \sum_{n=3}^k (2n+1)
$$
for all $k$.

Base Case:
$$
\sum_{n=3}^3 2^n \geq \sum_{n=3}^3 (2n+1).
$$
Induction step:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^{k+1}2^n&=2^{k+1}+\sum_{n=3}^k2^n\\&\geq 2(k+1)+1+\sum_{n=3}^k(2n+1)\\&=\sum_{n=3}^{k+1}(2n+1).
\end{align}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because $2^n\ge2n+1$ is valid from $n=3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not sure exactly how this happened, but I fixed these issues immediately and then your edit rolled back my changes.

Comment: Ah, probably happened with my format change.